# jquery auto-complete position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery auto-complete to perform a simple search, I would like to display my result under a text-box. currently when searching a user, it appends data on top of the text-box so i cannot see what I'am typing. This is what I have done through online suggestions:.

```
  $("#auto").autocomplete({
            position: { //does not work
                my: "left top ",
                at: "left bottom",
            },
            appendTo: "#results",
            messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function () { }
            },
```

I've tried this and it works but it only works after 2nd search:

```
   $(function () {
       $("#auto").autocomplete({
       source: data
        });
     $("#auto").autocomplete({
         source: data
             }).autocomplete("widget").addClass("fixed-height");
                });
```

Comment: well I have answered my own question via http://jsfiddle.net/ttueW/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the position option, specifically the offset property:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="auto" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var data = ['Java', 'JavaScript', 'C', 'C#', 'C++']
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: data , 
    position: {
        offset: '0 0' // Shift 0px to the left, 0px down.
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/67H8G/)**